# Bootstrap button group full width of parent - not equal width buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a Bootstrap btn-group to take the full width of its parent, but I don't want the buttons to be equal width.

I want all the buttons to take only the width they need except for one button that takes up the remaining width.

example:

```
------------------ width of parent -----------------
| btn 1                            | btn 2 | btn 3 |
```

or

```
------------------ width of parent -----------------
| btn 1 | btn 2 | btn 3                            |
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n95bavga/) and tell me if it is like you wanted.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="btn-group child">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary larger">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary normal">Samsung</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary normal">Sony</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  width:600px;
}

.child{
  width:100%;
}

.larger{
 width:60%; 
}

.normal{
 width:20%; 
}
```

Comment: I might go with that if I don't find something better... The problem is that the width of the smaller buttons should depend on their content. That is not the case with this solution.